# Replacing a class or method globally in a TypeScript project

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm working on a project written in `TypeScript` that imports and uses various third party libraries imported via the `package.json` file.

One of these libraries has a utility class (that other classes from the same library make use of) that exposes a method I would like to modify/replace.

Obviously the best option in this case would be to modify the source of this library directly and recompile it. However, I was wondering if there is a "quick and dirty" way to replace a class (or a method in a class) globally in a TypeScript project. Is this possible? And how would I do it?

Comment: You can create a local module and use that, if the package is open-source

Comment: @heaxyh The package is indeed open source. Any further pointers on how to do what you suggest? I admit I'm not the greatest typescript expert...

Comment: Is this utility class exported?  Can we have a more specific example of exactly what you want to change?

Comment: Just monkey-patch it? It works the same as in plain JavaScript, this is not specific to TypeScript. Or are you saying you also want to change the declared type of the method?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [pnpm patch](https://dimava.github.io/pnpm/cli/patch/) command to "quickly and dirty" change contents of dependencies

A better way may be to make your own fork ot the package, and publish it [in the scope of your organization](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-and-publishing-scoped-public-packages), then you should be able to change the version in package.json to your org's one, but I'm not sure how exactly (feel free to edit this answer)